Primal-dual simplex method for general LP
I've learned the primal-dual method for standard LP, but for a general LP written as
\begin{align}
    \min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n} ~~~ &c^\top x \\
    s.t. ~~& l^{s}\leq Ax \leq u^{s},\\
        &l^{x}\leq x \leq u^{x}
\end{align}
how do we choose the entering and leaving variables when using primal-dual simplex method without converting the problem back to its standard form?
